# Open Graph e Meta tags

Tags: php, facebook

Por algum motivo, o debugger do facebook não reconhece as meta tags do meu site, ele afirma inclusive, que há metatags no `<body>` sendo que eu as defino logo após o `<title>` no `<head>` (eu as chamo com um include no PHP).
O código está assim:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="br">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Rainbow 6: Club - By Players. For Players.</title>
AQUI ESTÁ A META TAG
<?php include("meta.php"); ?>

<noscript><?php echo $noscript; ?></noscript>
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home.css"/>
...outras tags
```

No arquivo meta.php está assim:

```html
<meta name="description" content="descrição" />
<meta name="keywords" content="keys" />
<meta name="Copyright" content="...." />
<meta name="Title" content="...." />
<meta name="autor" content="...." />
<meta name="company" content="..." />
<meta name="Distribution" content="Global" />
<meta name="Language" content="Portuguese" />
 <!-- Facebook -->
<meta property="og:title" content="titulo">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="titulo">
<meta property="og:url" content="url do site">
<meta property="og:image" content="url de uma img com 1200x630">
<meta property="og:description" content="descrição">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
```

Não entendo o porquê do erro. Alguem já passou por isso pode me ajudar?

Comment: Percebi que se eu retiro o include e ponho as metatags na própria página, o Facebook reconhece. Mas o problema é que são umas 30 páginas, então....

Comment: Tente trocar a extensão do arquivo que vc está fazendo o include de .php para .html e faz um teste para ver se resolve... é só uma ideia não sei se vai resolver

Comment: Consegui resolver salvando o arquivo sem o BLOOM